# Можно ли установить приоритет свайпа RecyclerView на SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Если свайпнуть сверху вниз посередине экрана, то включится метод onRefresh(), вместо прокрутки RecyclerView. Можно ли установить приоритет свайпа RecyclerView на SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: в таком случае вопрос - а зачем тогда вообще нужен `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: Чтобы обновлять данные в Recycler View

Comment: так он должен срабатывать только когда лист прокручен полностью в топ

Comment: В этом и дело, когда я снизу списка пытаюсь подняться, включается SwipeRefreshLayout